# strip-space in xslt not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file which looks somewhat like this

```
    <listopt>
        <name>Body Dumping Phases</name>
        <alias>dump-body</alias>
        <set_arg_label>phaseName</set_arg_label>
        <short_desc>Dump the internal representation of each method before and after phase


            <use_arg_label/>



        </short_desc>
```

I wish to get the following output

```
<listopt>
        <name>Body Dumping Phases</name>
        <alias>dump-body</alias>
        <set_arg_label>phaseName</set_arg_label>
        <short_desc>Dump the internal representation of each method before and after phase <use_arg_label/></short_desc>
```

I have used strip-space in the xsl file which is linked to the xml file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="short_desc" />
<xsl:template match="/"> ...
```

But nothing seems to happen. I still get the output file same as the input.
What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. I don't think `strip-space` is supposed to strip the white space in the first text node child of the `short-desc` element as that is not a pure white space text node. The white space after the `use_arg_label` should be stripped and is with the right environment, see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8b. So it all depends on how you use XSLT and if you run the XSLT (processor) in a way that it can strip the white space, it might not do that for instance if you provide a DOM tree as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it is better to use `normalize-space` for required node, see XSL below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--perform normalize-space for text in node-->
    <xsl:template match="short_desc/text()">                                               
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>                    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So for below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listopt>
        <name>Body Dumping Phases</name>
        <alias>dump-body</alias>
        <set_arg_label>phaseName</set_arg_label>
        <short_desc>Dump the internal representation of each method before and after phase


            <use_arg_label/>



        </short_desc>
    </listopt>
```

Result will be as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listopt>
    <name>Body Dumping Phases</name>
    <alias>dump-body</alias>
    <set_arg_label>phaseName</set_arg_label>
    <short_desc>Dump the internal representation of each method before and after phase<use_arg_label/></short_desc>
</listopt>
```